# How do I change the guild's icon?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am trying to change the guild icon but I have no idea how to finish the code.
this is what I have now:

```
HttpClient dude = new HttpClient();
         var b= await dude.GetStreamAsync("somelink");
            Image pic = new Image();
            await Context.Guild.ModifyAsync(x => x.Icon = pic.Stream.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClient link = new Httpclient();
var clonestream = new MemoryStream();
Stream stream = await link.GetStreamAsync("link");
stream.CopyTo(clonestream);
Image pic = new Image(clonestream);
clonestream.Position = 0;
await Context.Guild.ModifyAsync(x => x.Icon = pic);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: I answered my own question just to show I already figured it out.